# Spring Boot 2.2.5 - spring.datasource.data property in yaml

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, datasource, hikaricp

Recently we upgraded to spring boot 2.2.5
We used to use the property  spring.datasource.data to load SQL after "create" or "update" of the database.

Our Yaml looked like this:

```
--
spring:
    profiles: default
    application:
        name:"EMBEDDED"
    datasource:
        url: "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/somedb"
        driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
        username: postgres
        password: "some password"
        data: "classpath*:data.sql"
   jpa:      
      database: POSTGRESQL
      show-sql: false
      hibernate.ddl-auto: update
```

The important part is the "spring.datasource.data" property where we used to define a name of a SQL file that hibernate would run after updating the DB.

Note that we use the hibernate.ddl-auto to make that happen.

Now we have upgraded the spring boot and we also started using 2 data-sources as follows:

```
spring:
    profiles: dev
    application:
        name:"EMBEDDED-DEV"   
    datasource:
        src1:
            jdbcUrl: "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=DB1"
            username: user
            password: password
            initializationFailTimeout: 0
            data: "classpath*:data.sql"
        src2:
            jdbcUrl: "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=db2"
            username: user            
            password: password
            initializationFailTimeout: 0
            data: "classpath*:data.sql"        
    jpa:      
        database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
        show-sql: false
        hibernate.format_sql: true
        hibernate.ddl-auto: update
```

As you can see we have now 2 data sources, but when i try to add the "data" property as i used to do before i get this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Property data does not exist on target class com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig
```

Where should i put now the data property in order for it to work?

Comment: 2 datasources should be configured differently. Check this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7)

Comment: Thank you, i will check it. Just a note, the problem is only with the "data" property, meaning that we have no problem with the fact that we have 2 data sources  (this part works)

Comment: I see. what was your previous version?

Comment: we used spring boot version 1.5.21